# C++ - const vs non const member function - template with function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, pointers, variadic-templates

I have a code, that is havily using templates. One example is this:

```
template <class MT>
struct class_method_info;

template <class T, class Res, class... Args>
struct class_method_info<Res(T::*)(Args...)>
{
    typedef std::tuple<Args&&...> ArgsTuple;
    typedef T ClassType;
    typedef Res RetVal;
    static constexpr std::size_t ArgsCount = sizeof...(Args);
    static constexpr bool IsClassMethod = true;     
};
```

This works for the non-const member function pointers.

If I change `Res(T::*)(Args...)` to `Res(T::*)(Args...) const`, I can pass `const` function pointers. However, even if this is working a solution, it messed up my code, because now I have everything doubled and there are a lot of such things.

Is there any other way?

Comment: have you considered to create templated parent class with the implementation and pass all required template parameters there?

Comment: I dont know what your use case is, but I hope `std::mem_fn` did not meet your requirements otherwise you should give that a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a specialization for `const` `this`, that would inherit most of the implementation from the other one:

```
template <class MT>
struct class_method_info;

template <class T, class Res, class... Args>
struct class_method_info<Res(T::*)(Args...)>
{
    typedef std::tuple<Args&&...> ArgsTuple;
    typedef T ClassType;
    typedef Res RetVal;
    static constexpr std::size_t ArgsCount = sizeof...(Args);
    static constexpr bool IsClassMethod = true;
    static constexpr bool IsConstThis = false;
};


template <class T, class Res, class... Args>
struct class_method_info<Res(T::*)(Args...) const> : class_method_info<Res(T::*)(Args...)>
{
    static constexpr bool IsConstThis = true;
};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/z0vOz3O1tW4rzcVq)